# Don't know how to add o to a plot with R package dbplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to add a legend to a boxplot which I created with the R-package dbplot. Unfortunately I'm getting the error:

```
"Don't know how to add o to a plot"
```

Here is my sample code: (I've added sample data but I load the data from a **spark table!**)

```
cars <- c(27,37,9,11,47,29,39,41,18,30)
cars_s <- c(0,99,10,0,0,0,0,0,10,10)
sample_data <- data.frame(cars, cars_s)

sparkTable %>% 
   filter(cars > -1) %>% 
   dbplot_boxplot(x = cars_s, var = cars, coef = 1.5) +
   ggtitle("Boxplot Title") +
   labs(x = "status", y = "cars") +
   legend("topright", inset = .05, title = "Status", legend = as.character(c("0", "1", "2"))) + 
  theme_bw()
```

The output of my boxplot looks like this without the legend line

[image]

As described, I'm not able to add a legend.

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible and include sample data and load all relevant packages?

Comment: Sample data added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `dbplot_boxplot()` in `dbplot` doesn't support legends.

If it were an ordinary data.frame you would just add `color = x`:

```r
  library(tidyverse)
  mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

However, when working with a database you always have to compute in the database and then collect into memory in R. `dbplot` is a package that does this and the plotting for you. Now, boxplots are a bit special because you have to compute a number of columns such as `quartiles`, `inter range quartiles` and so on. So to do it by hand may be a bit hefty, since the legend won't add any necessary information in your case.

However, if you think the package should add this feature you can leave a feature request as an issue on the package's Github: https://github.com/edgararuiz/dbplot/issues

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I was not aware that dbplot is not able to add legends to the boxplot. However, this must be possible because the output of dbplot_boxplot is a ggplot2 boxplot in my opinion.

Comment: It is possible, but it is not as simple as it seems, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As FilipW suggested I left a feature request and got an answer very quickly from the developer of dbplot. His answer solved my problem. He wrote me that I should work with **db_compute_boxplot** instead of **dbplot_boxplot**. Because db_compute_boxplot returns a data frame with **boxplot calculations.** So, it is possible to add manually the boxplot and colours:

```
sparkTable %>% 
   filter(cars > -1) %>% 
   db_compute_boxplot(x = cars_s, var = cars, coef = 1.5) +
   ggplot() +
   ggtitle("Boxplot Title") +
   labs(x = "status", y = "cars") +
   theme_bw() +
   geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = cars_s,
      ymin = ymin,
      lower = lower,
      middle = middle,
      upper = upper,
      ymax = ymax,
      color = as.factor(cars_s),
    ),
    stat = "identity"
  )
```

Many thanks!